# append digits to a number - Matlab

Tags: matlab, numbers, append, digits

I have a column with only `whole numbers` in it, to which I need to append a number (say `11`) at the front -

```
data = (1:1300000)';
% append 11 to these numbers

newdata = [111 ;  112 ; 113 ; 114 ; ......]
```

Is there a way to do it without using `str2num` (due to speed issues) ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take the base 10 logarithm of `data`, you can find out by how much you have to multiply 11 so that you can turn this into a simple addition.

```
%# create some test data
data = [1 22 123];

%# add 11*10^x to data so that the two ones end up in front of the number
newData = 11*10.^(floor(log10(data))+1)+data

newData =
         111        1122       11123
```